# How to Rotate Count Plot In Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
sns.set(style = 'dark', palette = 'colorblind', color_codes = True)
ax = sns.countplot('Position', data = data, color = 'orange')
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel = 'Different Positions in Football', fontsize = 16)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel = 'Number of of Players', fontsize = 16)
ax.set_title(label = 'Comparison of Positions and Players', fontsize = 20)
plt.show()
```

After excuting this code the labels get Overlapped
[image]

Is there any way to rotate the image to prevent overlapping?

Comment: `orient='h'` should do it, no?

Comment: The graph remains the same

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll have to provide a complete example, it's very difficult without seeing your `data`: the docs, here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html suggest that using the orient keyword should work, so you could try `orient="v"`

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using

```
ax = sns.countplot('Position', data = data, color = 'orange')
```

Where 'Position' = x, try to use 'Position'=y, just like that:

```
ax = sns.countplot(y='Position', data = data, color = 'orange')
```

The rest of the code remains the same